# testing rails with rspec calling api with authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I am trying to write a test using rspec 2.12.2, to test an api written in rails 3.2.6.

However the authorization token is not being passed, have no issue calling this from curl.

get '/API/V1/voucher/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/redeem.json', {}, { 'Authorization' => 'Token token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}

the response back from the request from a overwritten method to return the error in json below.

```
def request_http_token_authentication(realm = "Application")  
    self.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Token realm="#{realm.gsub(/"/, "")}")
    self.__send__ :render, :json => { :error => "HTTP Token: Access denied. You did not       provide an valid API key." }.to_json, :status => :unauthorized
end
```

Comment: Is this a feature spec, or a controller spec?

Answer (score 0):

setting the header to this worked.

get '/API/V1/voucher/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/redeem.json', {}, { 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => 'Token token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}